# Relay how to write outputFields, getFatQuery, getConfigs for create new Item

Tags: graphql, relayjs

How to write `outputFields`, `getFatQuery`, `getConfigs` for create new item and update items list
Please take a look [gist](https://gist.github.com/ButuzGOL/9e7e7323db7d9b6ce28d) or [live](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20CreateCommentMutation%20extends%20Relay.Mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20getMutation()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20mutation%7B%20createComment%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getFatQuery()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20CreateCommentPayload%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%20%7B%20comments%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getConfigs()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getVariables()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20text%3A%20this.props.text%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Comment%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bid%2C%20text%7D%20%3D%20this.props.comment%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cli%20key%3D%7Bid%7D%3E%7Btext%7D%3C%2Fli%3E%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AComment%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Comment%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20comment%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Comment%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Story%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20_handleSubmit%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Relay.Store.update(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20CreateCommentMutation(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.refs.newCommentInput.value%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.refs.newCommentInput.value%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bcomments%7D%20%3D%20this.props.story%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20onSubmit%3D%7Bthis._handleSubmit%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EBreaking%20News%3C%2Fh1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EThe%20peanut%20is%20neither%20a%20pea%20nor%20a%20nut.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstrong%3EDiscuss%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bcomments.map(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comment%20%3D%3E%20%3CComment%20comment%3D%7Bcomment%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder%3D%22Weigh%20in%26hellip%3B%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ref%3D%22newCommentInput%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3D%22text%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AStory%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Story%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20story%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Story%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComment.getFragment('comment')%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20StoryHomeRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Home'%3B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20story%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20StoryQuery%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%20%7B%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('story')%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BStory%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20StoryHomeRoute()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLID%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLList%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLNonNull%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20mutationWithClientMutationId%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql-relay'%3B%0A%0Aconst%20STORY%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20comments%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20CommentType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Comment'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%7Btype%3A%20GraphQLID%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7Btype%3A%20GraphQLString%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20StoryType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Story'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20comments%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLList(CommentType)%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20CreateCommentMutation%20%3D%20mutationWithClientMutationId(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'CreateComment'%2C%0A%20%20inputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20new%20GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20outputFields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20story%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20StoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20STORY%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20mutateAndGetPayload%3A%20(%7Btext%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20newComment%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20STORY.comments.length%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20STORY.comments.push(newComment)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20newComment%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20story%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20StoryType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20STORY%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20mutation%3A%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Mutation'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createComment%3A%20CreateCommentMutation%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B)

Questions are

```js
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      ???
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [???];
  }
```

```js
  outputFields: {
    ???
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The `outputFields` in your schema make up the GraphQL type `CreateActivityPayload` that will be generated from your schema.js file. A mutation is like a regular query, but with side effects. In `outputFields` you get to decide what's queryable. Since your store is the only thing in your app that can change as a result of this mutation, we can start with that.

```js
outputFields: {
  store: {
    type: storeType,
    resolve: () => store,
  },
}
```

The fat query operates on these output fields. Here you tell Relay what could possibly change as a result of this mutation. Adding an activity could change the following fields:

```js
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on CreateActivityPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
      store {
        activities
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

Finally, the config tells Relay what to do with the query when it gets it, or even if it needs to be made at all. Here, you're looking to update a field after creating a new activity. Use the `FIELDS_CHANGE` config to tell Relay to update your store.

```js
getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
    fieldsIDs: {
      store: this.props.storeId,
    },
  }];
}
```

See more: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html

Comment: Note, your store should expose an ID, or you will have to reach into the client side store to get it: `RelayStore.getStoreData().getCachedStore().getDataID('store')`

Comment: If I have a `viewer` with `post` and `posts` on it, and I mutate a `post`, do I need to have its `outputFields` return a whole new `viewer` or can I have it return just the updated/new `post`? If I just return the `post`, how do I map it to everything that might change in the `getFatQuery`?

Comment: So long as the `post` has an id and you can make it available on the FooPayload type (the type returned by the mutation), you can update that record by using `FIELDS_CHANGE`. Relay will update whatever UI relies on that `post` record.